# Migrate from Windows 2008 SQL Server to SQL CE (for WebMatrix)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some stuff in my remote SQL Server 2008 DB. I want to put it inside my SDF database (the WebMatrix one). But I can't just copy the rows from Navicat (while viewing table for SQL Server 08) into the SDF database because some rows don't let you manually insert stuff.

So I need a way to "Migrate" from Windows SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server CE (.sdf).

---

I think I have the right tools to accomplish this, but would appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction.

I have:

1. Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate RC
2. Web Matrix
3. Navicat Premium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after hours of searching, I've managed to solve this issue.

---

[How to Migrate/Downsize a SQL Server database to SQL Server Compact 4.0 (and 3.5)](http://erikej.blogspot.com.au/2010/02/how-to-use-exportsqlce-to-migrate-from.html) has an extremely straightforward approach to doing this.

Like myself, you may need to download the following tools (and place them in the same directory as your CMD.exe file:

- [SQL Compact Command Line Tool](http://sqlcecmd.codeplex.com/downloads/get/386348)
- [SQL Compact data and schema script utility](http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/downloads/get/335673)